# Program wont change array value

Tags: arrays, parameters

(Win32 console app) Ok so i know its a bit to look at, but ive added as many helpful comments that i could think of, im sort of new to coding so if this is a quick fix i apologize for taking your time, ive searched high and low and cant figure this out. So, it prompts the user for a name, that works, then for a race, that works, but under the display function, it fails to show the updated stats (updated by which race you choose). although sometimes it will work with the hp/maxHP but not att nor def. im not sure if its something to do with the scope or what, ive tried all i know :/ thanks for your time and help :)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int stats[6] = {1, 10, 10, 1, 0, 0};//life(0), maxHp(1), hp(2), att(3), def(4), gold(5)

void shop();//goes to the shop
void fight();//goes to fighting area
void sleep();//refills hp
void welcome();//establishes name
void display();//hud
void whereTo();//travel selection
void doRace();//establishes name
void human();//race#1
void orc();//race#2
void dwarf();//race#3
string name;//variable for name

//Main
int main()
{
    welcome();
    doRace();
    while(stats[0]==1)
    {
        whereTo();
        cout << stats[1];
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    cout << "If you are reading this, you have DIED!\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void shop()
{
    display();
    cout << "To-be shoping area.\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}

void fight()
{
    display();
    cout << "To-be fighting area.\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}

void sleep()
{
    display();
    cout << "You rest completely..." << endl;
    stats[2] = stats[1];
    system("PAUSE");
}

void whereTo()
{
    display();
    cout << "Where would you like to go?\n\n Shop(1)\n Fight(2)\n Sleep(3)\n";
    int place;
    cin >> place;
    system("CLS");
    if(place==1)
    {
        shop();
    }
    else if(place==2)
    {
        fight();
    }
    else if(place==3)
    {
        sleep();
    }
else
{
    cout << "Please enter 1, 2, or 3.";
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    whereTo();
}
}

void display()//Header to everything
{
    system("CLS");
        cout << name << "                           HP: " << stats[2] << "/" << stats[1] << " Att: " <<     stats[3]     << " Def: " << stats[5] << "  Gold:" << stats[5] << endl << endl;
}

void welcome()//runs once, establishes name in beginning
{
    cout << "Welcome to my first RPG Program\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Enter your character's name\n\n";
    cin >> name;
    system("CLS");
}

void doRace()//choosing a race at the start
{
        cout << "What Race would you like to be?\n\n\n 1)Human (More Attack and Defense)\n\n 2)Orc (More Hp and Attack)\n\n 3)Dwarf (More HP and Defense)\n\n";
    int race;
    cin >> race;
    if(race==1)
    {
        human();
        cout << "You chose Human!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else if(race==2)
    {
        orc();
        cout << "You chose Orc!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else if(race==3)
    {
        dwarf();
        cout << "You chose Dwarf!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1, 2, or 3.";
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
        doRace();
    }
}


void dwarf()//sets the initial stats of the character based off of race selection
{
       stats[1] = stats[1] + 3;//maxHp
       stats[2] = stats[2] + 3;//hp
       stats[4] = stats[4] + 2;//def
}

void human()//sets the initial stats of the character based off of race selection
{
       stats[3] = stats[3] + 2;//att
       stats[4] = stats[4] + 2;//def
}

void orc()//sets the initial stats of the character based off of race selection
{
       stats[1] = stats[1] + 3;//maxHp
       stats[2] = stats[2] + 3;//hp
       stats[3] = stats[3] + 2;//att
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong index for def.  It should be 4

```
Def: " << stats[5].
```